# How can I check if a square block has the color black in it in a UIImageView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, a-star

I'm making an app with A* pathfinding. There is a black-and-white floorplan on a UIImageview, and I figure the way to make this work is to check if the tile that the A* method is currently looking at has any black in it - if it does, then this is a wall and the tile should be ignored. Even if only like half of the tile is black.

I figure you could just look through all the pixels, but this sounds very expensive. Is there an easier way? I don't have any code cause I don't know where to start with this. I'm hoping there is just some method that I could call.

Comment: More context would be helpful. You could scan these images and mark which tiles are 'black', then save that info associated with the image. Then every you use it, you load in the associated info to see which tiles are black instead of having to recalculate them.

Comment: Yea I'm hoping I don't have to do that, so any user can upload a floorplan and have the pathfinding just figure it out without any extra work.

Comment: You can do some smart calculations to speed it up - you don't need to check *every* pixel to see if there is a black one. Most likely, if you check 9 pixels (8 around perimiter, 1 in center), you'll see if there is any black (depending on how your floorplans look). But given your constraint that if there is even some black, you ignore it, you're going to have to do the calculations to ensure there is no black.